# Java & Swing - Is it possible to have two JDialogs popup at the same time?

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

Is it possible to have two JDialogs popup at the same time, second below first one?

Comment: yes without any restictions, untill JVM memory returns OutMemory exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is definitely possible if the second dialog's parent is the first dialog.